# Definir máximo número de items por hilera en una retícula

Tags: html, css, grid

Usé [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278350/5765312) para centrar las fichas de producto en la última hilera de una tienda online, funciona perfectamente.

Me gustaría saber si es posible definir un método para equiparar el número de artículos en función de la cantidad total, obteniendo el máximo número de artículos por fila, responsive y centrando todo el grupo.

Por ejemplo:
11 items = 4 + 4 + 3 para pantallas anchas
o 3 + 3 + 3 + 1 para medidas de pantalla estrecha

Esto es lo que tengo:

[image]

Esto es lo que me gustaría conseguir:

[image]

No sé el número exacto de elementos que tendrá cada sección, estoy buscando algo genérico para grupos con contenido par e impar.

Sé que no será posible un equilibrio para cualquier cantidad:

13 artículos = 5 + 5 + 3 / 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 / 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2

No se si es posible, alguna sugerencia?

Intentando razonar, si todas las tarjetas tienen el mismo ancho y margen, digamos 250px + 10px, quizás se pueda realizar algo con medidas para que solo quepan artículos en cada ancho.

Por ejemplo:

3 artículos = ancho de la hilera = 790px

4 artículos = ancho de la hilera = 1030px

Comment: Los items tendran tamaño fijo?

Comment: Ancho fijo, lo puse en la pregunta, 250px + 10px de separación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva

```css
#container {
float:left;
  margin:auto;
}
#general{
      width: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}
.item {
  float:left;
  flex: 0 0 calc(16.66% - 20px);
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width:130px;
  margin: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 790px) {
   
    #container{
       width:500px
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
   
    #container{
       width:700px
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="general">

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Está perfecto, no es exacto pero con ajustes se puede arreglar

Comment: me alegra mucho, ya tu lo ajustas al ecosistema